# product filtering for brand as checkbox and price slider using php,mysql and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

if u select on brand that will be checked and also check the price that also filtered but when i selected another brand that will not be selected please suggest me..
  i think it will not select multiple array brands.i will used php,jquery and mysqli.

```
<div class="widget-header">
                <h4 class="widget-title">Brand</h4>
            </div>    
            <div class="accordion-group" id="brandname">
            <?php

            $all_brand=$con->query("SELECT distinct brand FROM `mc_products_tbl` WHERE cat_id = '$_GET[cat_id]' GROUP BY brand");?>
            <?php foreach ($all_brand as $key => $new_brand) :
                                    if(isset($_GET['brand'])) :
                                        if(in_array(data_clean($new_brand['brand']),$_GET['brand'])) : 
                                            $check='checked="checked"';
                                        else : $check="";
                                        endif;
                                    endif;
                                ?>
                                   <input type="checkbox" value="<?=data_clean($new_brand['brand']);?>" <?=@$check?> name="brand[]" class="sort_rang brand" onchange="filterProducts()"><?=ucfirst($new_brand['brand']); ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div>

<div class="widget-header">
                <h4 class="widget-title">Price Range</h4>
            </div>    

                <div class="filter-panel">
                    <p><input type="hidden" id="price_range" onchange="filterProducts()" value="50,50000"/>
                      </p>
                    </div>

function filterProducts() {
var cat_id = $("#cat_id").val();
var subcat_id = $("#subcat_id").val();
var brand = check_box_values('brand');
var price_range = $("#price_range").val();
alert(cat_id);
alert(subcat_id);
alert(brand);
alert(price_range);
var dataString='price_range='+price_range+'&cat_id='+cat_id+'&subcat_id='+subcat_id+'&brand='+brand;
alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "left_listing_ajax_filter.php",
               data: dataString,

                cache: false,
                // beforeSend: function () {
                //$('.container').css("opacity", ".5");
                //},
               success: function (data) {
                     if (data != "") {  
                        $('#results').html(data);
                        //$('.container').css("opacity", "");
                                      }
                                         }
                });


    function check_box_values(check_box_class){
        var values = new Array();
            $("."+check_box_class+":checked").each(function() {
               values.push($(this).val());
            });
        return values;
    }
    $('.sort_rang').change(function(){
        $("#search_form").submit();
        return false;
    });

    }
```

please suggest me....if you select second time that will not move to left_listing_ajax_filter file..please suggest me...i am trying to resolve this problem please help me..

Comment: You can pass array in url

Comment: no i don't pass array values in the url..please suggest me..first time that will be filtered but when i select second product that time it should not be worked

Comment: See `brand` isn't it array?

Comment: ya brand is array...first time that will be filtered but when i select second product that time it should not be worked please suggest me..if you select second time that will not move to left_listing_ajax_filter file..please suggest me...

Comment: i take brand as array but that was not supported to store multiple values actually if i select brand second time Best,Butterfly_Day displays but that was not filtered..please suggest me...

Comment: Pass `brand` as string (like `,` separated  string) in url then do operation on php

Comment: please guide me??

Comment: hellooooooooooooo..any one is there please answer my question..

Comment: please guide me??